# Exporting points as points, text as text (when exporting to svg)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, export, svg

I am using QGIS as an intermediary step  to making an SVG/AI file.

I have layers which are point shapefiles, where the points in each layer are labelled.

However, when I export to SVG, QGIS does two things:

- All the points and text in a layer becomes a single object in SVG (i.e. when you click and drag one in Inkscape, you drag all the points and text in that layer).
- The labels are not text in Inkscape, but rather paths.

Is there any way to export my QGIS file to SVG/AI, in a way that solves both problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set this while exporting to SVG:

[image]

Then after opening the SVG in AI you have to ungroup the exported text and points:

[image]